# Android SimpleCursorAdapter flow

Tags: android, loader, simplecursoradapter

Someone know how SimpleCursorAdapter get database info with no have any content provider interaction? I searched in the docs, but i don't understand yet

I make the Udacity course for learn Android and I use this Fragment, but i can't understand the flow.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    mForecastAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
            getActivity(),
            R.layout.list_item_forecast,
            null,
            // the column names to use to fill the textviews
            new String[]{WeatherContract.WeatherEntry.COLUMN_DATETEXT,
                    WeatherContract.WeatherEntry.COLUMN_SHORT_DESC,
                    WeatherContract.WeatherEntry.COLUMN_MAX_TEMP,
                    WeatherContract.WeatherEntry.COLUMN_MIN_TEMP
            },
            // the textviews to fill with the data pulled from the columns above
            new int[]{R.id.list_item_date_textview,
                    R.id.list_item_forecast_textview,
                    R.id.list_item_high_textview,
                    R.id.list_item_low_textview
            },
            0
    );

    mForecastAdapter.setViewBinder(new SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder(){

        @Override
        public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex) {
            boolean isMetric = FormatServices.isMetric(getActivity());
            switch (columnIndex) {
                case COL_WEATHER_MAX_TEMP:
                case COL_WEATHER_MIN_TEMP: {
                    // we have to do some formatting and possibly a conversion
                    ((TextView) view).setText(FormatServices.formatTemperature(
                            cursor.getDouble(columnIndex), isMetric));
                    return true;
                }
                case COL_WEATHER_DATE: {
                    String dateString = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                    TextView dateView = (TextView) view;
                    dateView.setText(FormatServices.formatDate(dateString));
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    final ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listview_forecast);
    listView.setAdapter(mForecastAdapter);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            /*String forecast = mForecastAdapter.getItem(position);
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), forecast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), DetailActivity.class)
                    .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, forecast);
            startActivity(intent);*/
        }
    });
    return rootView;
}
```

Someone can help-me to understand SimpleCursorAdapter flow?

Comment: Why do you pass null to the ```SimpleCursorAdapter``` constructor where you should be passing a ```Cursor```?

Comment: @NathanWalters, I don't know why! It's for that i don't understand SimpleCursorAdaptar behavior. I just use Udacity Android course example. You can see more complete https://github.com/bkawakami/Udacity-Sunshine/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/sunshine/fragment/MainFragment.java

Comment: Just pass it a cursor pointing to data that you want to render in the list. Do you know you to get a cursor from a database query?

Comment: @NathanWalters, yes, I know how get, but I don't understand this specific flow. I actualize my last comment with my github repository. https://github.com/bkawakami/Udacity-Sunshine/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/sunshine/fragment/MainFragment.java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could understand how it works SimpleCursorAdapter. I using the Loader to get information and added after

```
@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
    mForecastAdapter.swapCursor(data);
}
```